# how to sort a string alphabetically java

Tags: java, alphabetical

I want to sort a string in JAVA alphabetically, as follows
Capital letter and lowercase letter followed
AaBbCcDdEeFfGg.
for example if I put AbaC return me AabC
thanks!!

Comment: It's too early for new years wishes, until that time you'll have to show some effort. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this using `Arrays.sort`, if you put the characters into an array first. (It must be an array of `Character` objects rather than `char` primitives, in order to use a custom case-insensitive comparator.)

```
// put the characters into an array
Character[] chars = new Character[str.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
    chars[i] = str.charAt(i);

// sort the array
Arrays.sort(chars, new Comparator<Character>() {
    public int compare(Character c1, Character c2) {
        int cmp = Character.compare(
            Character.toLowerCase(c1.charValue()),
            Character.toLowerCase(c2.charValue())
        );
        if (cmp != 0) return cmp;
        return Character.compare(c1.charValue(), c2.charValue());
    }
});

// rebuild the string
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(chars.length);
for (char c : chars) sb.append(c);
str = sb.toString();
```

Comment: This will split UTF-16 surrogates.

Answer (score 8):

You may try to look for [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) and then try like this:-

```
Collections.sort(caps, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Something like this:-

```
private static Comparator<String> ALPHA_ORDER = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        int x = String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(str1, str2);
        if (x== 0) {
            x= str1.compareTo(str2);
        }
        return x;
    }
};

Collections.sort(list, ALPHA_ORDER);
```

**EDIT:-**

For sorting alphabetically in a string try like this:-

```
Collator col = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("en", "EN"));
String s = "AbaC";
String[] s1= s.split("");
Arrays.sort(s1, col);
String sorted = "";
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++)
{
  sorted += s1[i];
}
System.out.println(sorted);
```

Comment: OP wants to sort characters in strings, not a list of strings.

Comment: Which is a matter of turning the string in a list of characters, that's the trivial part.

Comment: @Boann:- Updated my answer. Hope that makes it better?

Comment: Now it doesn't handle the case-insensitive requirement.

Comment: @Boann:- Yes corrected that!

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but now it doesn't handle OP's requirement that capital letters come first. I'm not sure how to change that with a Collator.

Comment: Actually, neither does my answer in every case.... crap.

Answer (score 3):

Turn the String into a character array, then compare the int values of each character in your sort.

Methods needed:
`String.toCharArray();`